# How to add `android` Kotlin DSL to classpath in buildSrc module?

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to make some extension methods in `buildSrc` to use them in other modules' `build.gradle.kts`-files

Particularly I need to extend `com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension`. For that, I seem to need `com.android.library` in `buildSrc`'s classpath. Trying to achieve that with

```
plugins {
   id("com.android.library") apply false
}
```

gives me `Plugin [id: 'com.android.library', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:` error.

What is the correct setup for this purpose?

Full content of `build.gradle.kts` from `buildSrc` below:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      google()
      jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3")
   }
}

plugins {
   `kotlin-dsl`
   id("com.android.library") apply false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore everything I previously posted. Here is how I was able to use `LibraryExtension`. However, ymmv, this seems heavy handed.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

// ...snip...

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3")
}
```

If all you want is access to the class, you want it as a dependency, not a plugin. I'm still not sure how to make this work as a plugin in buildSrc, so hopefully this gets you what you need.

Comment: And that, sir, is an absolutely correct answer! I found it myself the same day I posted the question in this article: https://medium.com/@nathan.lecoanet/gradle-extension-with-buildsrc-and-the-kotlin-dsl-ea3e06977a21 . Now accepting your answer. Hopefully, more people will end up here, because that article did not appear easily in google search...